# convolutional Mixture Density Networks in tensorflow

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I know that tensorflow probability supports mixture density networks now with the following layer :

https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/MixtureNormal

I was wondering if there is any *convolutional* version of this layer or maybe any existing library or implementation of this layer.

something along the lines mentioned here :
https://www.h-its.org/software/deep-convolutional-mixture-density-networks/

Any help is appreciated.